# Qt Quick Controls 2 Loading another qml ui on pressing OK in message

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to build a login form for a Windows Desktop Application using Qt Quick Controls 2. I want the login page to display a success or failure message. On success after user presses `Ok` the login form should be hidden from view and another `SettingsForm` should be displayed. On login failure login form should be displayed again after user presses `Ok` Both Login Form and Settings Form have their seperate `qml` and `ui.qml` files.

I am unable to implement the functionality of switching to SettingsForm on Login Success. This is what I have got so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 900
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Welcome!")
    maximumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width

    minimumHeight: height
    minimumWidth: width
    x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
    y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Page1Form {
            login.onClicked: {
                if (username.text == "a" && password.text == "a") {
                    message.title = "Login success!"
                    message.visible = true

                }
                else {
                    message.title = "Login Failed! Try Again."
                    message.visible = true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Code for Message dialog:

```
Dialog
{
            id: message
            width: 300
            height: 100
            x:-10
            standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
            modal: true
            onAccepted: visible=false

}
```

I tried inserting :

```
SettingsForm {

}
```

after `message.title = "Login success!"` but it doesn't work.

Edit:

The dialog box looks like this on successful login:

[image]

Comment: Where do you instantiate your `Dialog`? What kind of `Dialog` is it? The one from [`QtQuick.Dialogs`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickdialogs-index.html) or from [`QtQuick.Controls 2.x`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-dialog.html)?

Comment: Instantiated in Page1Form.ui.qml file. Its from QtQuick.Controls

Comment: Added an image of the message dialog to the question

Answer (score 0):

Store the success of the login in a flag. Then handle the dialog's `accepted()`-signal, to fire a custom `loginSucceeded()`-signal which you then use anywhere else to move on.

```
Page1Form {
    id: p1f
    signal loginSucceeded()
    property bool success: false

    login.onClicked: {
        if (username.text == "a" && password.text == "a") {
            success = true
            message.title = "Login success!"
            message.visible = true

        }
        else {
            success = false
            message.title = "Login Failed! Try Again."
            message.visible = true
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: p1f.message // I guess the Dialog is exposed via the property 'message'
        onAccepted: if (p1f.success) loginSucceeded()
}
```

Then you might e.g. ask the `SwipeView` to move on, `onLoginSucceeded`
(I guess, you were planning on using the `SwipeView` to manage your screens?)

```
SwipeView {
    id: formSwiper

    interactive: false // otherwise someone might swipe away your login screen.
                       // Since you use QtQuick.Controls 2.2 it should be available

    Page1Form {
         onLoginSucceeded: formSwiper.currentIndex++ // Move on!
         [...]
    }

    SettingsForm {
         [...]
    }
}
```

> **Disclaimer:** I don't have QtQuick.Controls 2.2, so I can't test the `Dialog`

Comment: "Then you might e.g. ask the SwipeView to move on, onLoginSucceeded" I didn't get this part. How to go to SettingsForm from here?

Comment: Ok I guess I should have mentioned it was for a windows application. Also, I am not sure why the SwipeView is being used, it was already there in the default template and being a newbie I didn't think much and just edited the code pieces. I should have used `Loader` I believe. Now when I try to replace the `SwipeView` with `Loader` the entire design shifts to the top left and the background image vanishes.

Comment: `SwipeView` works perfectly fine on desktop applications, but `Loader` would be the better, probably. If you have problems with the `Loader` please open another question. Don't forget to post the code of `Page1Form` to reproduce your error. Also please don't forget to mark this answer as correct, if it is. If you do not understand everything, explain your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the implementation for swiping from LoginForm Page to SettingsForm page in your SwipeArea implementation:

```
    SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    anchors.fill: parent
    property int loginPage : 0     // index for Login page
    property int settingsPage : 1  // index for Settings page

    Page1Form {
        login.onClicked: {
            if (username.text == "a" && password.text == "a") {
                message.title = "Login success!"
                message.visible = true
                swipeView.currentIndex = swipeView.settingsPage // Swiping the view to settings page
            }
            else {
                message.title = "Login Failed! Try Again."
                message.visible = true
                swipeView.currentIndex = swipeView.loginPage // current page view is kept as login page (if you want you can remove this line)
            }
        }
    }
    SettingsForm {

    }
    }
```